# WPF Toolkit BusyIndicator

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, wpftoolkit

I have a problem trying to update the UI. What I need it is that after displaying the `BusyIndicator`, need the message changes, and when finished 5 seconds, display another message for two seconds and then hide the `BusyIndicator`. Thx!

**XAML**

```
<xctk:BusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}" DisplayAfter="0">
    <xctk:BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <mahApps:ProgressRing IsActive="{Binding IsBusy}"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding ShowMessage}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </xctk:BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate>

    ...

</xctk:BusyIndicator>
```

**XAML ViewModel**

```
public string ShowMessage
{
    get { return _showMessage; }
    set
    {
        _showMessage = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("ShowMessage");
    }
}

private void Save()
{
    ShowMessage = "Wait please...";

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        IsBusy = true; // Show busyindicator and ProgressRing

        Thread.Sleep(5000); // 5 seconds to see the animation (Here is a SQL insert)

        /// Hide ProgressRing only

        ShowMessage = "Save complete.";

        Thread.Sleep(2000); // 2 seconds to see "ShowMessage"

    }).ContinueWith(x =>
    {
        IsBusy = false; // hide busyindicator and ProgressRing

        ...

    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but, ShowMessage = "Save complete."; is not running on the UI thread. For RaisePropertyChanged to work it must, so you need insert another Continuation and Task to execute ShowMessage using FromCurrentSynchronizationContext.